# Deleting from an Observable collection

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have an observable collection whiich I want to remove a specific instance item from.

e.g.

`data[1].ChildElements[0].ChildElements[1].ChildElements.RemoveAt(1);`

This works fine, however, as this is relating to deleting child elements from a treeview, I want to dynamically create the above statement dependant on what level of the treeview is clicked. So i could want:

`data[0].ChildElements[1].ChildElements.RemoveAt(0);`

or

`data[1].ChildElements.RemoveAt(0);`

I know the id's of the parent items which I have stored away in a list, e.g.

`0
1
0` or `1,0`

My question is how do I go about creating the above statement when I dont know exactly how many items there are going to be in the list collection?

Thanks.

Comment: The title of the question is a little misleading. You may be using an ObservableCollection specifically but the question has nothing to do with ObservableCollection. The problem would be the same for any recursive data structure whether it's implemented with an ObservableCollection or an array or a List.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes old school does it best.

```
  static void RemoveByPath(YourClass currentNode, int[] path)
  {
       for (int i = 0; i < path.Length - 1; i++)
       {
            currentNode = currentNode.ChildElements[path[i]];
       }
       currentNode.ChildElements.RemoveAt(path[path.Length-1]));
  }
```

in case you don't have a "Root" `YourClass` instance (I suspect you do but just in case) add:-

```
static void RemoveByPath(IList<YourClass> data, int[] path)
{
    if (path.Length > 1)
    {
        RemoveByPath(data[path[0]], path.Skip(1).ToArray());
    }
    else
    {
        data.RemoveAt(path[0]);
    }
}
```

then if you do want something clever you might turn these into extension methods.

Comment: i like the iterative version instead of the recursive, personally.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Recursive functions, which can give you Actual/Current node, and the you can find out bound ObservableCollection and remove from it.

Comment: I already have a recursive function which finds the parent id's and selected item, I just dont know how to generate the statement to actually delete the item from the collection.

Comment: given your Collection structure is the same (i.e. parent always has child "Nodes" collection, can u not use the same recursive function to give you the ObservableCollection that you want?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
private void RemoveSpecificInstance(IList<int> ids, ObservableCollection<SomeClass> currentCollection)
    {
        if (ids.Count == 0) 
        {
            // The initial collection didn't have children
            return;
        }
        else if (ids.Count == 1)
        {
            currentCollection.RemoveAt(ids.Single());
        }
        else
        {
            int index = ids.First();

            RemoveSpecificInstance(ids.Skip(1).ToList(), currentCollection[index].ChildElements);
        }
    }
```